# Add an element to each component of a sequence

Tags: scala

I was wondering if a function exists in Scala that does this:

```
Seq[T] x A => Seq[T x A]
```

Or an example:

```
(1,2,3) 4 -> ((1,4), (2,4), (3,4))
```

I realized I could do this by simply looking up Scala standard collection reference, yet there does not seem to be an easy way of looking by type (as opposed to hoogle). Of course I could also write my own combinator.

Comment: There isn't a built in function that does this since you can implement it in one line using `map` or `zip`

Comment: `List(1,2,3).map(_ -> 4)` ?

Comment: @TomerShetah I wasn't looking for laziness, but since thre is no other answer, i have accepted it.

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo. The most straight forward way is the comment above, which I didn't want to include inn my answer since it was here before I read the question. I tried to bring some added value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it lazily you can do:

```
def zipWith[T, A](s: Seq[T], a: A): LazyZip2[T, A, s.type] = {
  s.lazyZip(LazyList.continually(a))
}
```

Please note that this results in an unmaterialized value. In order to get the results you need to materialize them. For example, the following:

```
println(zipWith(List(1, 2, 3), 4).toSeq)
```

will output:

```
List((1,4), (2,4), (3,4))
```

while

```
println(zipWith(List(1, 2, 3), 4))
```

outputs:

```
List(1, 2, 3).lazyZip(LazyList(<not computed>))
```